# repeat value assignment in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script. It is supposed to read a .txt file containing a list of domains. Each time it will take one line of this .txt file, find its ip address and write it to output:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
                ipV= 
                while IFS= read -r ip; do
                        if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                                ipV="${ip}-"
                        fi
                done < <(dig +short "$line")        
                ipV=${ipV%-}

done < URLs.txt
```

My problem is that sometimes "dig +short "$line" doesn't return a result. In this case I want to repeat the action until it finally find the ip address (until ipV is not empty). In fact I want to do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
                ipV= 
                while IFS= read -r ip; do
                        if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                                ipV="${ip}-"
                        fi
                done < <(dig +short "$line")        
                ipV=${ipV%-}
                if [ -z "$ipV" ] #if empty
                    #repeat the above steps
                else
                    echo "$ipV" >> out.csv
                fi

done < URLs.txt
```

but since I'm new to bash, I don't know how to handle this. What can I do to repeat value assignment to ipV if it is empty?

Comment: It looks like you just answered the question yourself. What about `ipV=;while [ -z "$ipV" ]; do while IFS= read -r ip; do if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then ipV="${ip}-"; fi; done < <(dig +short "$line"); ipV=${ipV%-}; done;`

Comment: @vdavid I don't know how to say "repeat the above steps" using bash.

Comment: I typed my comment too soon, my bad. Please take a look at my edited comment.

Comment: `while` already *is* a "repeat these steps" command; you just need to add an outer one that changes the condition to something like "while the ip variable is empty", instead of "while this read succeeds".

Comment: And in your last question on the topic, I already suggested `until`, a variant on `while` that's perfectly suited for the use case at hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry I didn't see "until" in my previous post. I will take a look at how it works.

Comment: Bet `sed` can do it could you put short example of URLs.txt and desired output?

Comment: @Ivan, how is `sed` going to run `dig` to find the associated IP addresses?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, with `e` modificator to `s` command.

Comment: @Ivan, `system()`? That's dangerous (as in, evil-security-bugs dangerous) to use, and non-GNU systems rightly don't support it. I wouldn't want someone telling a program I run that `$(rm -rf ~)` is a URL to cause my home directory to disappear.

Comment: `echo 'google.com' | sed 's/\(.*\)/dig +short \1/e'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrounding your code in an `until` loop achieves the narrow request:

```
ipV=
until [[ $ipV ]]; do
  while IFS= read -r ip; do
    [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]] && ipV+="${ip}-"
  done < <(dig +short "$line")        
done
```

---

I would also consider:

```
set -o pipefail # make an entire pipeline fail if any part fails

while IFS= read -r line; do
  ipV=; retries=10
  until [[ $ipV ]] || (( retries <= 0 )); do
    ipV=$(dig +short "$line" | grep -E '^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+$' | tr '\n' '-')
    (( --retries ))
  done
  if [[ $ipV ]]; then
    echo "${ipV%-}"
  else
    echo "ERROR: Gave up retrieving IP for $line after 10 retries" >&2
  fi
done <URLs.txt >out.csv
```

Comment: but I got this error: ./t5.sh: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
./t5.sh: line 12: <(dig +short "$line"): ambiguous redirect

Comment: That's certainly for the first variant, as the second one doesn't have any process substitutions at all.

Comment: Interesting, though, if you're able to get that with the code exactly as given; we should be closing each process substitution when the loop at hand exits. If the issue is reproducible, it'd be a good SO question on its own.

Comment: The second one doesn't find the IPs at all. I'm facing this error each time I execute the code: ERROR: Gave up retrieving IP for google.com after 10 retries

Comment: Current version? The first one called the counter variable `retries_left` when assigning it, vs checking `retries` later; that bug was fixed ~5 minutes ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208278/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-helen).

Answer (score 0):

Sed?

```
$ cat URLs.txt 
stackoverflow.com
google.com
github.com

$ sed 's/\(.*\)/dig +short \1/e' URLs.txt 
151.101.193.69
151.101.129.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.65.69
64.233.164.138
64.233.164.113
64.233.164.101
64.233.164.102
64.233.164.100
64.233.164.139
140.82.118.3
```

Update on @CharlesDuffy comment, i assumed that OP is creating this URLs.txt by himself, no? But lets test this.

```
$ cat URLs.txt
stackoverflow.com
google.com
github.com
$( ls -la )
```

Will give us this

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)/dig +short \1/e' URLs.txt
151.101.129.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.65.69
173.194.222.100
173.194.222.113
173.194.222.101
173.194.222.102
173.194.222.139
173.194.222.138
140.82.118.4
Invalid option: -rw-r--r--
Usage:  dig [@global-server] [domain] [q-type] [q-class] {q-opt}
            {global-d-opt} host [@local-server] {local-d-opt}
            [ host [@local-server] {local-d-opt} [...]]

Use "dig -h" (or "dig -h | more") for complete list of options
```

But this one can have some bad consequences

```
$ cat URLs.txt 
stackoverflow.com
google.com
github.com
| ls -la

$ sed 's/\(.*\)/dig +short \1/e' URLs.txt
151.101.129.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.65.69
151.101.1.69
173.194.222.139
173.194.222.101
173.194.222.102
173.194.222.100
173.194.222.113
173.194.222.138
140.82.118.3
итого 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 ivan ivan  4096 фев 25 09:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 86 ivan ivan 12288 фев 25 08:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan  1003 фев 19 17:48 file
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   393 фев 17 14:45 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    40 фев 21 09:48 headers
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    27 фев 21 11:19 id.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    44 фев 20 11:37 input.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   121 фев 21 12:16 lines
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   195 фев  7 17:21 lines.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   160 фев 21 11:53 out
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   210 фев  7 17:12 output
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ivan ivan   157 фев 21 17:46 test
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    21 фев 21 17:44 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    22 фев 21 17:46 test3
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    49 фев 25 09:30 URLs.txt
```

And `;` also can hurt

```
$ cat URLs.txt 
stackoverflow.com
google.com
github.com
; ls -la

$ sed 's/\(.*\)/dig +short \1/e' URLs.txt
151.101.65.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.129.69
151.101.193.69
173.194.222.100
173.194.222.113
173.194.222.138
173.194.222.101
173.194.222.139
173.194.222.102
140.82.118.4
g.root-servers.net.
h.root-servers.net.
a.root-servers.net.
m.root-servers.net.
i.root-servers.net.
c.root-servers.net.
j.root-servers.net.
l.root-servers.net.
k.root-servers.net.
d.root-servers.net.
f.root-servers.net.
e.root-servers.net.
b.root-servers.net.
итого 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 ivan ivan  4096 фев 25 09:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 86 ivan ivan 12288 фев 25 08:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan  1003 фев 19 17:48 file
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   393 фев 17 14:45 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    40 фев 21 09:48 headers
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    27 фев 21 11:19 id.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    44 фев 20 11:37 input.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   121 фев 21 12:16 lines
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   195 фев  7 17:21 lines.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   160 фев 21 11:53 out
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   210 фев  7 17:12 output
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ivan ivan   157 фев 21 17:46 test
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    21 фев 21 17:44 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    22 фев 21 17:46 test3
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan    49 фев 25 09:32 URLs.txt
```

Comment: If your `URLs.txt` contains `$(rm -rf ~).troll`, you're going to have a *very* bad day.

Comment: Also, the whole reason the OP is here is that sometimes `dig` fails for them and they want to retry until it succeeds. This answer doesn't do that.